# how to collect spark sql output to a file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my spark sql script which loads a file and uses SQL on top of it, I want to collect the output from the sql query and write it to a file, not sure how to can anyone help.

```html
   //import classes for sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

// createSchemaRDD is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a SchemaRDD.
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD


//hdfs paths
val warehouse="hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/hive/warehouse/"
val customers_path=warehouse+"people/people.txt"
customers_path

//create rdd file called file
val file=sc.textFile(customers_path)

val schemaString="name age"

import org.apache.spark.sql._



val schema =
  StructType(
    schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

val rowRDD=file.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0),p(1).trim))

val peopleSchemRDD=sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)

// Register the SchemaRDD as a table.
peopleSchemRDD.registerTempTable("people")

// SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.
sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from people").collect().foreach(println)
System.exit(0)
```

Comment: In the code you provided the result of the query is just a number, right? You're asking how to write a number to a file in Scala?

Comment: yes I want the number or output to be written to a file , is there a way of doing this ?

Comment: val op=sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from people")
val c=op.collect()
val rdd=sc.parallelize(c)
rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/cloudera/op")
System.exit(0)

Comment: I recommend using collect only if you aren't worried about the driver gathering the information and the extra time it takes depending on the input size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to count the number of lines in a big file on HDFS and write it to another file:

```
import java.nio.file.{ Files, Paths }
val path = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/hive/warehouse/people/people.txt"
val rdd = sc.textFile(path)
val linesCount = rdd.count
Files.write(Paths.get("line_count.txt"), linesCount.toString.getBytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
//import classes for sql
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

// createSchemaRDD is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a SchemaRDD.
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
import sqlContext.implicits._

//hdfs paths
val warehouse="hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/hive/warehouse/"
val customers_path=warehouse+"people/people.txt"
customers_path

//create rdd file called file
val file=sc.textFile(customers_path)

val schemaString="name age"

import org.apache.spark.sql._



val schema =
  StructType(
    schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

val rowRDD=file.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row(p(0),p(1).trim))

val peopleSchemRDD=sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)

// Register the SchemaRDD as a table.
peopleSchemRDD.registerTempTable("people")

// SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.
val op=sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from people")
val c=op.collect()
val rdd=sc.parallelize(c)
rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/cloudera/op")
System.exit(0)
```

Comment: No reason to create a 1-element RDD just to write out a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
peopleSchemaRDD.registerTempTable("people")
val op=sqlContext.sql("select * from people").count().toString
val pw=new PrintWriter(new File("path"))
pw.write("count of people:"+op+"\n")
pw.close()
```

create a temporary table named people, then write a query to get the required output and count function thats counts the number of rows later the output converted to tostring.
this stored value in object op is called using the print writer to write it into the text file.
if in case the people column consist of duplicate values then use the distinct keyword to distinguish the unique values in the sql query.